# Change User agent before loading page in webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a an in which we want to change the user agent depending on the webpage the webview is going to load.

i.e before the page is actually loaded check the URL and then change the user agent.
So I have the below code

```
if (!(page.contains("google"))){
    grabit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(null);

}else{
    grabit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

}
```

This should in theory work but im not sure where to put it.
I know you can set a webviewclient which has a onPageStarted and onPageFinished method, but is there say a BeforePageStarted method? Or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

The shouldOverrideUrlLoading function in the WebViewClient will be called as soon as the WebView gets the Url it'll be loading.